# Unable to get 2nd value of JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having problem in getting value of "orderDate" as it returns nothing. Works fine with "orderNumber" tho.

Here's how I get the "orderNumber":

```
var object = JSON.parse(data);
$('#jsonresponse').html(object.orders[0].orderNumber);
```

And here's how I try to get the "orderDate" but returns nothing:

```
var object = JSON.parse(data);
$('#jsonresponse').html(object.orders[0].orderDate);
```

My JSON below:

```
"orders": [
    {
        "orderNumber": "ORDER_900123",
        "orderDate": "2014-08-28T17:10:10Z",
        "orderType": "OR",
        "customerId": "19827",
        "poNumber": "PO_12345",
    }
]
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: problem solved with my own mistakes. I was using different JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

It [worked for me](https://jsbin.com/jejolusadi/1/edit?html,output) once I removed the trailing comma after `"PO_12345"`.

(JSON is stricter than JavaScript and disallows trailing commas in object syntax.)

Is it possible you introduced that in between your tests?

Comment: It didn't work with my test wonder why. I need to double check my js plugin.

Comment: OMG, silly me. I was getting different JSON file so no wonder there's no key name as orderNumber in the file. Sorry for troubling. But your solution helps me to think. :)

Answer (score 0):

OMG, silly me. I was getting different JSON file so no wonder there's no key name as orderNumber in the file. Sorry for troubling.